# Why does proceed() give an error

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I have the following aspect:

```
aspect NullifyNoResultException {

    Object around(..) : execution(public Object com.example.*.*(..) {
        try { return proceed();    
            } catch (NoResultException e) { 
                return null;
            }                  
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the call to proceed gives an error in Eclipse:

> The method proceed() is undefined for the type NullifyNoResultException

When I build in maven -> `mvn install` I get no errors.
But that makes no sense because I'm still missing an import for the `NoResultException` so maven should complain about that.
Instead it just builds and does not complain.

How do I get Eclipse to stop complaining about the `proceed()`?
and how do I get this aspect to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few syntax errors in your code example. When I correct them, the following example  runs fine. BTW, I defined my own `NoResultException` because I have no Java EE installed.

```java
package javax.persistence;

public class NoResultException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

```java
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        System.out.println(app.valueReturningMethod(1, "two"));
        System.out.println(app.exceptionThrowingMethod(1, "two"));
    }

    public Object valueReturningMethod(int i, String string) {
        return "normal result";
    }

    public Object exceptionThrowingMethod(int i, String string) {
        throw new NoResultException();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

aspect NullifyNoResultException {
    Object around() : execution(public Object com.example..*(..)) {
        try {
            return proceed();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
normal result
null
```

Comment: Wow thanks, will have a look at it now and let you know how it goes.